# Java Optional return value only if present

Tags: java, lambda, functional-programming, option-type

Is it possible to return the Optional value from method only if it's present, but if it's not just continue with a normal method flow. Something like this:

```
public Message processMessage(Message message) {
        // ErrorMessage is subclass of Message; only returned if validator found some violations, otherwise empty optional
        Optional<ErrorMessage> error = validator.validate(message);

        if (error.isPresent()) return error.get();

        // returns different possible subclasses of Message
        return service.processMessage(message);
    }
```

Is there any prettier way to write this?

Comment: `orElseGet`, and you put the rest of the method in the lambda

Comment: In your example just: `error.orElse(service.processMessage(message))` should be enough

Comment: No, that doesn't work. Because then it expects the return type to be "ErrorMessage". But return type from the service can be any other subtype of message.

@Pau orElse expects the exact same type as the Optional invoking it. So it I invoke it from "ErrorMessage" optional, it will expect the same return type.

Comment: Shouldn't `Message` be immutable, and its invariants checked at instantiation?

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is indeed that the return types do not match. `orElseGet` only works when the supplier returns a subtype of the `Optional` type.

To work around this, you can force a cast to the parent type first:

```
return error.<Message>map(m -> m).orElseGet(() -> service.processMessage(message));
```

or equivalently:

```
return error.map(m -> (Message) m).orElseGet(() -> service.processMessage(message));
```

Answer (score 1):

I simply would go with [`Optional.orElseGet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElseGet-java.util.function.Supplier-) and an explicit cast in between:

```
public Message processMessage(final Message message) {
  return validator.validate(message)
    .map(Message.class::cast)
    .orElseGet(() -> service.processMessage(message));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to test it currently but it may give u an idea, may be you can implement something like below

```
return Optional.ofNullable(message)
.map(validator::validate)
.orElseGet(service::processMessage)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at that snippet, it looks like the `validate` method on the `validator` doesn't quite have the proper return type. Consider using e.g. `io.vavr.control.Either` or `io.vavr.control.Validation` monad. Take a look at a possible signature for `validate`:

```
Either<SpecificError, ? extends Message> validate(Message message);
```

Now the `map` and `fold` combinators can be used like so:

```
validator
    .validate(message)
    .map(message -> service.processMessage(message))
    .fold(error -> new ErrorMessage(error), success -> success); // the left function can be replaced by Function.identity()
```

to yield `Message`.